# Necessary and sufficient conditions for a matrix to be positive definite

Tags: matrices

I have a symmetric matrix with the following form:

\begin{bmatrix}
2\alpha_{1,1} & -\alpha_{1,2} & -\alpha_{1,3} \\
-\alpha_{1,2} & 2\alpha_{2,2} & -\alpha_{2,3} \\
-\alpha_{1,3} & -\alpha_{2,3} & 2\alpha_{3,3}
\end{bmatrix}

, where $\alpha_{i,j}$ is a real positive value

I want to understand under what conditions this matrix is positive definite (PD).

I know that if the matrix is strictly diagonally dominant then it will be PD, i.e. it will be PD if:

\begin{equation}
2\alpha_{1,1} > \alpha_{1,2} + \alpha_{1,3} \\
2\alpha_{2,2} > \alpha_{1,2} + \alpha_{2,3} \\
2\alpha_{3,3} > \alpha_{1,3} + \alpha_{2,3}
\end{equation}

However the matrix can also be PD without being strictly diagonally dominant. Can anyone show what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the above matrix to be PD?

A variant of the same problem is to show PD necessary and sufficient conditions for a generic matrix with the same structure and size $A$, where the scalar factor multiplying the diagonal elements is $A-1$.

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: See the necessary conditions for a matrix to be PD here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveDefiniteMatrix.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion